# Como colocar bordes a una fila secundaria en Datatables

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, datatables

Estoy haciendo uso de la librería de JQuery [Datatables](https://datatables.net/) y con ella estoy construyendo unas filas secundarias en la que deseo mostrar información cargada desde un procedimiento almacenado por medio de una llamada a AJAX, el problema que estoy presentando es que las filas secundarias o filas hijas (child row) según la documentación oficial de Datatables así la llaman, es que en ellas no se ven los bordes como se ven en la fila padre (parent row)

El codigo con el cual construyo mi tabla es el siguiente:

**Index.php**

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="es">

<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">    
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="libraries/css/estilos.css" type="text/css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="libraries/datatables/dataTables.bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="libraries/js/jquery-1.12.3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="libraries/datatables/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
    <script src="libraries/datatables/dataTables.bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="Javascript.js"></script>
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>  
    <link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.24/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>    
   <link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.24/css/dataTables.bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
   <link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/fixedheader/3.1.8/css/fixedHeader.bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
     <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.24/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
     <script src= "https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.24/js/dataTables.bootstrap.min.js"></script> 
   <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/responsive/2.2.7/js/dataTables.responsive.min.js"></script>
   <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/fixedheader/3.1.8/js/dataTables.fixedHeader.min.js"></script>

    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/1.10.7/integration/bootstrap/3/dataTables.bootstrap.js"></script>
    
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="libraries/img/icon.png" />
</head>

<body>
    <div class="cuerpo">
        <div class="dividir menu">
            <div class="centrar-vertical">
                <img src="libraries/img/logo.jpg" width="200" height="40" alt="Test" class="img-responsive">
            </div>
            <div class="alinear-derecha centrar-vertical">              
                <button id="logout-btn" class="btn btn-default">Cerrar Sesión</button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="tablaDatatable">  
        <table id="example" class="table table-striped table-bordered dt-responsive nowrap" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
            <thead>
                <tr>  
                    <th></th>                
                    <th>Orden de compra</th>
                    <th>Fecha de Orden de Compra</th>
                    <th>TipoMoneda</th>     
                </tr>              
            </thead>
        </table>        
        </div>
    </div>
    
</body>
</html>
```

El siguiente es la funcion Javascript con el cual creo mi fila secundaria y la llamada a AJAX para cargar los datos:

**Javascript.js**

```
/* Formatting function for row details - modify as you need */
function format(d) {
    // `d` is the original data object for the row
    console.log(d);
    
    return '<table cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0" border="0" style="padding-left:50px">' +
        '<tr>' +      
        '<td><strong>Fecha de Recepción: </strong></td>' + '<td><strong>No. Factura:<strong></td>' +  '<td><strong>Codigo Art:<strong></td>' +  '<td><strong>Descripcion Art:</strong></td>' + 
        '<td><strong>Cant:</strong></td>' + '<td><strong>Precio:</strong></td>' + '<td><strong>IVA:</strong></td>' + '<td><strong>Lote:</strong></td>' + '<td><strong>Configuración:</strong></td>' +
        '<td><strong>Pte. de Entrega:</strong></td>' +  '<td><strong>Pedido:</strong></td>' + '<td><strong>Recibido:</strong></td>' +
        '</tr>' +
        '<tr>' +
        '<td>' + d.FechaFactura + '</td>' + '<td>' + d.Factura + '</td>' + '<td>' + d.Codigo + '</td>' +  '<td>' + d.Descripcion_Articulo + '</td>' +
        '<td>' + d.Cantidad + '</td>' + '<td>' + d.Precio + '</td>' + '<td>' + d.Iva + '</td>' + '<td>' + d.Lote + '</td>' + '<td>' + d.Configuracion + '</td>' +
        '<td>' + d.PendienteEntrega + '</td>' +  '<td>' + d.Pedido + '</td>' + '<td>' + d.Recibido + '</td>' + '<td>' + 
        '</tr>' +    
        '</table>';     
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#example').dataTable( {
        responsive : true,
         ajax : {
             "type": 'POST',
             "url" : 'test.php',  
             "dataType": 'JSON',             
             "cache": false,
             "data": {
                 'param' : 1,   
               
             },
         },
         language : {
            "lengthMenu": "Mostrar _MENU_ registros",
            "zeroRecords": "No se encontró nada",
            "info": "Mostrando del _START_ al _END_ de un total de _TOTAL_",
            "infoEmpty": "No hay registros",
            "emptyTable": "No hay datos para mostrar",
            "loadingRecords": "Cargando...",
            "processing": "Procesando...",
            "search": "Buscar:",
            "infoFiltered": "(filtrado de un total de _MAX_ registros)",
            "paginate": {
                "first": "Primera",
                "last": "Última",
                "next": "Siguiente",
                "previous": "Anterior"
            }
         },    
         columns: [          
             {
                 "className":      'details-control',
                 "orderable":      false,
                 "data":           null,
                 "defaultContent": ''
             },
             { "data" : "OrdenCompra" },
             { "data" : "FechaOrdenCompra" },
             { "data" : "TipoMoneda" },
             { "data" : "Estatus" }                  
        ],
         order : [[1, 'desc']]
    } );

    
    // Add event listener for opening and closing details
    $('#example').on('click', 'td.details-control', function () {
        var tr = $(this).closest('tr');
        var row = $('#example').DataTable().row(tr);

        if (row.child.isShown()) {
            // This row is already open - close it
            row.child.hide();
            tr.removeClass('shown');
        }
        else {
            // Open this row
            row.child(format(row.data())).show();
            tr.addClass('shown');
        }
    });

});
```

No se si no estoy cargando correctamente las librerías adecuadas o me hace falta hacer uso de alguna clase en especifico de Datatables.

Me sentiría muy agradecido si me ayudan a solucionar este detalle con los bordes de las tablas.

Comment: De hecho, en mi respuesta a [tu otra pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/443731) agrego una clase a las filas secundarias; de tal manera que si agregas a css `.child-row td{ border: 1px solid; }` verás los bordes.

Comment: @Sal Puedes apoyarme identificando en que clase de agregaste el css, no lo logro identificar

Comment: Las filas secundarias (tr) tienen la clase `child-row`

Comment: @Sal Puedes indicarme por favor en una respuesta los cambios que debo hacer en mi código para darle así validez

Answer (score 0):

Agrega un clase al momento de crear los renglones hijo:

```
$('#example').on('click', 'td.details-control', function () {
        var tr = $(this).closest('tr');
        var row = $('#example').DataTable().row(tr);

        if (row.child.isShown()) {
            // This row is already open - close it
            row.child.hide();
            tr.removeClass('shown');
        }
        else {
            // Open this row
            row.child(format(row.data())).show();
            row.child()[0].classList.add('child-row'); // Agrega clase
            tr.addClass('shown');
        }
    });
```

A partir de ahí podrás estilizar:

```
.child-row td{ border: 1px solid; }
```